# Bitbucket pipeline cannot find the file in the test folder: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python, pytest, bitbucket-pipelines

I am getting the following error in the bitbucket pipeline:

```
E   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/tests/Test_input.csv does not exist: '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/tests/Test_input.csv'
```

[But the file exist: check the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Yuk.png)

It is working on my system but not in bitbucket, should I add the path to bitbucket-pipelines.yml? How?

Here is the bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: python:3.7.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - pip install swolfpy-inputdata
          - pytest
```

and here is my pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
python_paths = swolfpy_inputdata
testpaths = tests
python_files = tests/test_*.py  tests/*_test.py
minversion = 5.4
addopts = --verbose --durations=10 --color=yes  --cov=swolfpy_inputdata
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the screenshot, the file that does indeed exist is called `Test_Input.csv` (uppercase `I`). You're getting `FileNotFoundError` for `Test_input.csv` (lowercase `i`). Please make sure that your test expects the filename that is actually present.